# How to calculate number of leaves taken in a month between two dates?

Tags: mysql

My Table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
leave_id     emp_id       leave_from      leave_to       status
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1              1          2015-09-29      2015-10-2      accepted
2              1          2015-10-30      2015-11-2      accepted
```

In above table, How to find number of leave taken in a month?

Example:

In September, `Employee 1` has taken `2 leaves` (on 29th Sep and 30th Sep)

In October, `Employee 1` has taken `4 leaves` (on 1st Oct, 2nd Oct, 30th Oct and 31st Oct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` and date arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(greatest(leave_from, '2015-09-01'),
                least(leave_to, '2015-09-30')) + 1
from mytable t;
```

Just modify the constants for another month.

You can put this into an aggregation:

```
select emp_id,
       sum(datediff(greatest(leave_from, '2015-09-01'),
                    least(leave_to, '2015-09-30')) + 1)
from mytable t
where leave_from <= '2015-09-30' and leave_to >= '2015-09-01'
group by emp_id
```

Comment: Thanks.  The main function is returning `minus` values, due to that result is wrong for some cases. Ex: 2015-11-18 to 2015-11-19. May be `least()` function should be first argument in `datediff()`

Comment: @Hearaman-హేరామన్ . . . Arrgh!  Why do MySQL and SQL server have the arguments in opposite order?